# order of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ list all elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

show that the group $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ has order 6 by listing all its elements

---

I think that $GL(2,Z_2)$ is 2x2 matrices with $Z_2$ elements that is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 
               \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} 
,\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 
               \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix} $$

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 
               \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} 
,
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 
               \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 
               \\ 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 
               \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} $$
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 
               \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 
               \\ 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 
               \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 
               \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 
               \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} 
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 
               \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 
               \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 
               \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 
               \\ 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix} 
$$

I got that there are 15 elements so that would make it order of 15. but there **are suppose to be 6** right?

Comment: How many of those are invertible?

Comment: ok did not know that thanks got the 6

Comment: You've listed the $16$ elements of $M(2,\mathbb Z_2)$, not $GL(2,\mathbb Z_2)$.

Comment: There shall be 16 matrices in (2,ℤ2), and you missed 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 
               \\ 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$$
but the (2,ℤ2)  has 6 matrices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition, elements in $GL(2,Z_2)$ have nonzero determinants, so you have to delete those matrix with determinants equals to 0.